# Passing variables from Jquery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried everythinng anmad cannot get this prograam to work.  This is a chess program.  When a user double clicks on a square on the board, the cell should be added to the form in the move_to/move_from variable.

Here are code snippits:

```
<?php
 $results = array(array("Br", "Bn", "Bb", "Bq", "Bk", "Bb", "Bn", "Br"),array("Bp", "Bp", "Bp", "Bp", "Bp", "Bp", "Bp", "Bp"),
            array("", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),array("", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),array("", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
            array("", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),array("Wp", "Wp", "Wp", "Wp", "Wp", "Wp", "Wp", "Wp"),
            array("Wr", "Wn", "Wb", "Wq", "Wk", "Wb", "Wn", "Wr"));

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">


    <head>
        <title>Jquery Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" href="jq.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
<!-- Uses Session Variables -->
        <body>
            <div id="main">
            <fieldset  id="main_fieldset">
                <table  cellspacing="100">
                    <tbody >
                        <tr>
                            <td class="b1">8</td><td class="d1" id="a8"><?php echo $results[0][0];?> </td><td class="a1" id="b8" ><?php echo $results[0][1];?>  
                                </td><td class="d1" id="c8"> <?php echo $results[0][2];?> </td><td class="a1" id="d8"> 
                                <?php echo $results[0][3];?> </td><td class="d1" id="e8"><?php echo $results[0][4];?>  </td><td class="a1" id="f8"> 
                                <?php echo $results[0][5];?> </td>
                                <td class="d1" id="g8"> <?php echo $results[0][6];?> </td><td class="a1" id="h8"> <?php echo $results[0][7];?>  </td>
                        </tr>
```

snip..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.a1').click(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color","grey");
        });
}); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.a1').dblclick(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color","blue");
            move_from = $(this).attr("id");
            $.post('jq_test.php',move_from);
            alert(move_from);
    });
});

    <p><a href="jq_test.php?move_from">x</a></p>

<?php 
                    echo "this is the variable   ";echo $_GET['move_from'];
                    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

snip...

```
<?php       
    echo <<<HTML
            <form method="post" action="jq_test.php">
            Move From<input type="text" name="move_from"> </input><br /><br />
            Move To  <input type="text" name="move_to"></input><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Enter Move"></input>

            </form>
    HTML;
?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Search passing a value from jQuery to PHP and you get tons of questions

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript is using `$.post()`, but you're retrieving from `$_GET` in PHP. Switch to `$_POST` in PHP instead.

Comment: As well, you're not providing a name for your POST value. It should be `$.post('jq_test.php',{'move_from': move_from});`. Right now it's just a raw bit of data going across (you could probably read it from `php://input`).

Comment: how about `var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_REQUEST);`. Does that show anything? If they're blank, then your javascript isn't sending anything.

Comment: This is what I get: array(0) { } array(0) { }

Comment: Yep... your ajax call isn't passing anything to the PHP script.

Comment: Thanks.  Now what??  I surely do not know what to do.

Comment: Don't know, offhand. most of my ajax work has been done in mootools. I'd start by instrumenting/logging the heck out of your ajax function to make sure it's firing right, pulling the right data out of the form, etc... As well, using something like FireBug or HTTPFox to see exactly what's being sent client<->server.

Comment: The error console shows nothing and Firebug shows nothing.  Would you be able to look at my complete code [offline]?  I'm sure there is an obvious error somewhere that I am missing.

Comment: Look at this snippet <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.d1').dblclick(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color","blue");
      move_from = $(this).attr("id");
      $.post('jq_test.php',{data:'move_from'});
      alert(move_from);
   });
}); 

</script> 

    <p><a href="jq_test.php?move_from">x</a></p>

 
<?php 
       echo "this is the variable   ";echo $_POST['move_from'];
       var_dump($_GET);
?>

Comment: To the above snippet, I get an error "missing ; before statement" in this block  <?php echo "this is the variable ";echo $_POST['move_from']; var_dump($_GET); ?>  Does that help w/ the debugging?

Comment: Thanks.  BUT, the error is in this PHP  block:   <?php echo "this is the variable ";echo $_POST['move_from']; var_dump($_GET); ?>  I understand that it comes up in the JavaScript error console, but I am clueless as to what it is.  Help and advice, please

Comment: PHP errors do not show up in javascript consoles. They're completely independent. There's no error in this php block. The error is in your javascript somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  Found the error.  Nothing on the error console now.  It is not clear to me how to use HTTPFox.  Any good tutorials?  I'm going to try HTTPFox now. For what should I look?

Comment: Here is my Ajax call, and it works:<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a1').dblclick(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color","blue");
      move_from = $(this).attr("id");
//      $.post('jq_test.php',{data: "move_from"});
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "jq_test.php",
  data: 'move_from',
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(){
     alert( "Yippie " );
 }
  });
//      alert(move_from);
   });
}); 
However, I get this error:Notice: Undefined index: move_from in /var/www/jq_test.php on line 160 array Advice and help, please.

Comment: that's a php error, so dump out the post/request arrays and see what's showing up. httpfox is easy to use. hit "start", do your ajax stuff, and you'll see the client<->server stuff showing up in httpfox. it lets you view the headers and bodies of each request.

Comment: Requests: 00:00:13.054 0.455 392 1578 GET 200 text/html http://localhost/jq_test.php

00:00:13.286 0.239 381 (258) GET (Cache) text/css http://localhost/jq.css

00:00:13.391 0.163 401 (6032) GET (Cache) text/css http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css

00:00:13.500 0.407 379 (29910) GET (Cache) application/javascript http://localhost/jquery-1.5.2.min.js

00:00:13.910 0.467 389 (51785) GET (Cache) application/javascript http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js

Comment: Header--Request:
(Request-Line) GET /jq_test.php HTTP/1.1

Host localhost

User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.19) Gecko/20110430 Iceweasel/3.5.19 (like Firefox/3.5.19)

Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate

Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Keep-Alive 300

Connection keep-alive

Comment: Header - Response (Status-Line) HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date Wed, 22 Jun 2011 02:48:16 GMT

Server Apache/2.2.19 (Debian)

X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.6-12

Vary Accept-Encoding

Content-Encoding gzip

Content-Length 1359

Keep-Alive timeout=15, max=100

Connection Keep-Alive

Content-Type text/html

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help.....No POST data shown. In PHP, "undefined index" means that the variable has not previously been assigned a value.  In jQuery move_from is assigned a value, and displayed with an alert.  Additionally, there is an alert in the Ajax statement which shows that it completed properly.  Now what??

Comment: Look at the httpfox stuff. you'd see in the request headers/body somewhere a `move_from=...` bit, which'd indicate it got sent over the wire. if it did get sent, then you'd have to investigate why PHP's not processing it.

Comment: THough, looking at the headers you've posted above, it shows `GET /jq_test.php`, which means you're doing a GET, not a POST, but there's no `move_from` on the GET query line, so something's strange.

Comment: Not offhand. You'll just have to bang on it with larger hammers until something starts working.